# How to transfer variables to a subprocess in bash

Tags: bash, variables, parallel-processing, parent-child, subshell

I posted a question about an hour ago that elicited no responses, I'm now trying something different and I'm gonna simplify my question by including less code, but if you want to look at the rest of the code I'm using please check my last question [Parallel Processes in bash bitcoin monitor that records to sql leaking data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182907/parallel-processes-in-bash-bitcoin-monitor-that-records-to-sql-leaking-data) . I can't get these variables to successfully transfer to the subshell ./test. thank you for your help. The Array's IP Port Name and Address are defined outside of the for loop and I can put in an echo command to verify they are coming through.

```
for (( c=0; c<=$id-1; c++ ))
  do
    UnitIP=${IP[$c]}
    UnitPort=${Port[$c]}
    UnitName=${Name[$c]}
    UnitActive=${Active[$c]}
    sh -c ". ./test && echo \$UnitIP \$UnitPort \$UnitName \$UnitActive"
  done
```

Comment: The title should be rephrased to a subprocess instead of a subshell. The latter would not require exports.

Comment: The simplest, self contained test case for this would be `var=value; sh -c 'echo $var'`

Comment: @that-other-guy: that is a subprocess that happens to be a shell, not a subshell. This is a subshell: `var=value; ( echo "$var" )`

Comment: @Scrutinizer Maybe you should be correcting the question's title instead?

Comment: Thanks @that-other-guy, I did not realize I could edit :D ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just export them in parent shell:

```
export UnitIP=${IP[$c]}
export UnitPort=${Port[$c]}
export UnitName=${Name[$c]}
export UnitActive=${Active[$c]}
./test.sh
```

All the variables will become available in `test.sh` ( you don't need to source it )

Comment: I'm actually a little ashamed that that worked, thank you. Also for anyone who views this thread another big part of my problem is you can't run multiple nc's at once run ncat instead